# Excel spreadsheet that updates financial data via a query every 1 to 15 mins then copies to another sheet which collates this data when it changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I would really appreciate some help with this project that i am looking to start, i have a worksheet that uses a query which updates every 1 to 15 mins from a financial instruments prices website once this has updated every 1 to 15 mins i would like the data to be automatically saved to another sheet where it is collated in a new column each time so a record of each update is maintained.

i am happy to supply the sheet with the query already setup.

I've tried to find something online for this but it seems that although pieces of this request exist there is no answer to all of this question~!!!

Thanks in advance would be a real life saver!!

Jamie

Comment: You won't find a single resource to answer all of your requirements, you have to piece the various bits together.

Comment: So, you have a query which updates at set intervals, and you want to copy that data into another Sheet in a new column? I wouldn't mind looking at your Sheet, can you comment a link to it?

Comment: I'm happy to send a copy of the spreadsheet if thats easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a webquery that outputs its results to a normal Excel range and not to a range "formatted as table", Assuming the query is on "Sheet1" and the table is named "Table1", Assuming the copy must go to Sheet2, column A.
Paste this code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents moQ As QueryTable

Private Sub moQ_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If Success Then
        moQ.Destination.CurrentRegion.Copy
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim olo As ListObject
    Set moQ = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").QueryTables(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the above, as i have mentioned the query updates say every 15 mins which as u enquired is in the form as a table i then want each update to be saved using the time stamp so it would be column +1 for each query update

Comment: apologies i already mentioned the above let me use what u have given me and i will let you know if it works!! thanks in advance !!

Comment: would it be possible to sent you the spreadsheet as i really dont have your level of expertise ;)

Comment: Find my website url in my profile. My email address is listed at the bottom of my web page.

Comment: excellent will do this now, thanks

Comment: Sent your workbook back. The problem was that you are using a webquery, which returns its result to a normal range, not to a table so I had to modify moQ_AfterRefresh and Workbook_Open a little bit. I have updated the post above.

Comment: thanks for this, I've downloaded it and added the code but don't think that i have done  it right as nothing has happened when it updates.

Comment: It will start working after saving and re-opening the file and enabling macro's